# How to save job's info (parameters, status...) in database?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm using spring batch to read data from file and write the data to database.
It works fine, but I want the job's info (parameters, status...) to be saved in the "dataSourceBatch" database.

My batch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.0.xsd
    ">

<bean id="dataSourceBatch"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batchdb?characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
</bean>


<bean id="myWriter" class="org.jobs.MyWriter" />
<bean id="myReader" class="org.jobs.myReader" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true" />

<bean
    id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceBatch" />
<!-- 
 <bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>
-->

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher"
    p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
    p:jobRegistry-ref="jobRegistry" />

<!-- 
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" data-source="dataSourceBatch"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
    table-prefix="BATCH_" />
-->
<bean
    id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean"
    p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager" />

<bean
    id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />



<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders="true" />


<batch:job id="insertToDBJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="insertToDBStep">
        <batch:tasklet
        transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk
            reader="myReader"
            writer="myWriter"
            commit-interval="2" />
        </batch:tasklet>
        <batch:end on="COMPLETED" />
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

In my search I found:

```
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" data-source="dataSourceBatch"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE"
    table-prefix="BATCH_" />
```

But by using this "jobRepository" I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:241)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:602)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:811)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:871)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(JdbcJobInstanceDao.java:117)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:127)
```

I'm excuting the job with this code:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classPathXmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("batch.xml");
classPathXmlApplicationContext.start();
// launch the job
JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher)classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean("jobLauncher");
Job job = (Job)classPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean(jobName);
JobParametersBuilder jobParametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date());
id++;
jobParametersBuilder.addLong("id", id);
jobLauncher.run(job, jobParametersBuilder.toJobParameters());
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's your id's scope?  It looks like it is 0 multiple times and you are getting a dupe key, assuming JOB_INSTANCE_ID is the primary key.  Can you instead use an identity column?

Comment: I tried to change the "JOB_INSTANCE_ID" column in the "batch_job_instance" table to identity column, but now I get this exception: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_PARAMS(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, KEY_NAME, TYPE_CD, STRING_VAL, DATE_VAL, LONG_VAL, DOUBLE_VAL) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`batchdb`.`batch_job_params`, CONSTRAINT `JOB_INSTANCE_PARAMS_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`) REFERENCES `batch_job_instance` (`JOB_INSTANCE_ID`)); nested exception is co

Comment: tnx for the try, but I got another exception

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my database and created it again, now it works :)

Yes, it was that simple

How to create the database: http://www.javabeat.net/articles/272-the-spring-batch-infrastructure-1.html